# How do I use Jquery Cookie to show recently viewed products?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am trying to understand how I setup Jquery Cookies for recently viewed products on my Shopsite store. Shopsite uses static HTML pages.

Starting with the cookie itself to what HTML i need, can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Cookies? I mean, because you can use LocalStorage that is "better" and native from HTML5.